# Animations stretching geometry

Tags: three.js

I read that the latest threejs exporter added support for multiple animations so I created a quick experiment and exported a model with the latest plugin..after a bit of playing around with the code I managed to get each of the animations within the model playing, however the geometry is getting skewed horribly.

I'm pretty sure the issue is related to the following error: "gl.getProgramInfoLog() WARNING: Could not find vertex shader attribute 'position' to match BindAttributeLocation request." but not positive. Maybe I'm just not aware of something, such as a particular blender export flag configuration or something else that needs to be set within the code. Here's the important parts:

```
for (var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++) {
  var mat = materials[i];
  mat.skinning = true;
}

scene.add(mesh);

// add animation data to the animation handler
var animations = [];

for(var a in mesh.geometry.animations) {
    THREE.AnimationHandler.add(mesh.geometry.animations[a]);
    var animation = new THREE.Animation(mesh,mesh.geometry.animations[a].name);
    animations.push(animation);
}

animations[0].play();
```

Any ideas guys? Here's a screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6zdGNflpdJLSVVHemszWWFTTHc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm pretty sure the warning is about something else :)

Comment: yeah I'm an idiot. Didn't realize the new features were part of the blended animation class which is in dev. FYI I found some pretty sweet resources (http://ssatguru.appspot.com/yofrankie/yofrankie.html). Free / good quality animated models are always a pain in the ass to find.

Comment: Oh! Do you fancy putting together an example with those models and sending a PR? ^^

Comment: yeah definitely! May need a bit of time to get on that but it'd be fun :)